# Error while importing flat file (CSV) in SSMS 17.5

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssms

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but when trying to import a CSV file (with no headers and text qualified (")) using the new "Import Flat File" in SSMS, I get this error:
"A column named foo already belongs to this datatable (System.Data)".

It fails right after I enter the tablename and it starts trying to preview the data. I've loaded other similar files just the same and I don't think the format is wrong. Am I doing something wrong and is there a workaround?

[image: img]

SSMS 17.5 importing into SQL Server 2016

Comment: What does the table look like? My guess would be that you've got 2 columns named 'foo'.